# Dropdown with only three colors

Tags: html, css

I managed to set three colors for an input type color dropdown, but I only need to display the three selected colors, not all of them. Is it possible? This is my code. Thanks.

```
<input type="color" list="presetColors" class="form-control">
            <datalist id="presetColors">
                <option>#ff0000</option>
                <option>#00ff00</option>
                <option>#0000ff</option>
            </datalist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not the answer but it solves the issue.

```js
let button = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
let palette = document.querySelectorAll(".palette");

for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].onclick = function() {
    palette[0].classList.remove("black", "blue", "red", "orange");
    palette[0].classList.add(button[i].className.split(" ")[0]);
  };
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  margin: 0.2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.orange {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

.palette {
  margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="black button"></div>
  <div class="blue button"></div>
  <div class="orange button"></div>
  <div class="red button"></div>
</div>
<div class="palette"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `input` to a `select`. Then pass that option a class and set the background.

```css
select.form-control option.class1 { 
    /* Whatever color  you want */
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
select.form-control option.class2 { 
    /* Whatever color  you want */
    background-color: #00ff00;
}    
select.form-control option.class3 { 
    /* Whatever color  you want */
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<select type="color" list="presetColors" class="form-control">
        <datalist id="presetColors">
            <option class="class1" >#ff0000</option>
            <option class="class2">#00ff00</option>
            <option class="class3">#0000ff</option>
        </datalist>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Julian. Correct, but as you can notice on the code snippet, it displays the three colors and the rest of the colors available on the pallete. I need to show only those three colors so the user can select just one of those three.

Comment: You were right, please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Julian. No, its not working for me. At least on Safari and Chrome. It just display a select with the three HEX codes in there as normal text.